# Can I use a custom font in Microsoft Word?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, fonts, microsoft-word-2007

I created a custom font with Fony, and I want to use it in Word. I have it installed in the the system fonts, but Word won't use it, presumably because of security. Does anyone know why this happens, or how to fix it?

Comment: Does your font work anywhere else on your system (e.g. notepad)?

Comment: yup, notepad works fine.

Comment: Just to be clear, which operating system and version of Word are you using? There may be issues with fonts if you are on a Mac. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/295062

Comment: I saw that, and I wasn't sure if any of that applied. I am using Windows 7 Professional SP1 and Word 2007.

Comment: when you say it wont work, what happens? Does it not show up in the list? Does it make your selected text rectangular blocks or invisible?

Comment: It doesn't show up in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fony](http://hukka.ncn.fi/?fony) seems to create bitmap fonts only, and those are [not available in Microsoft Word](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=163059) starting with Word 97 I believe (but are available in some other applications, including Notepad).